# WatchConnectivity attempting to send data to Watch app

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, watchkit, watchconnectivity

I'm trying to send data from my iOS app to the Watch app. I'm using the updateApplicationContext for this.

I have a json file that I converted in NSDictionary and tried to send it. But there is an error, here it is:

> [WCSession updateApplicationContext:error:]_block_invoke failed due to WCErrorCodePayloadUnsupportedTypes

The file is correctly read.

Now here is the code that tries to send the data.

```
NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data"
                                                         ofType:@"json"];
    NSLog(fileName);
    if (fileName) {
        NSData *jsonData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
        NSDictionary *data = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData
                                                              options:0
                                                                error:&error];

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Something went wrong! %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Rsens info: %@", data);
            [WatchSessionManager.sharedManager updateApplicationContextWithApplicationContext:@{@"json": data} error:&error];
        }
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't find file!");
    }
```

I read somewhere that the types that we could send were limited, but the dictionary was allowed. I'm sending a dictionary though.

Can you find what is the error?

**[SOLUTION]**

I found out that there were values of type long in my dictionary. In my JSON I had some properties that were transtyped in type long. Here is one of the properties before:

```
"state": 0
```

I just put my numbers in string quotes.

```
"state":"0"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the dictionary's content.
WatchConnectivity dictionaries can only contain [property list types](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html).

Comment: I converted my json file information to NSData and NSData is a property list type. Shouldn't it be okay?

Comment: I found out that there were values of type long in my dictionary.
In my JSON I had some properties like
`"state": 0`
which was transtyped in long. I just put my numbers in string quotes.